# TypeError: buf is not a numerical tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, pickle

I am trying to encode the `image` or `frame` taken from `webcam` and sending it to server while decoding I am getting this error

I am trying to encode and decode using the following code

```
import cv2
import cPickle
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    data = cPickle.dumps(frame)
    res = cPickle.loads(data)
    small_frame = cv2.imdecode(res,1)
    print(res)
```

I am getting error while decoding. I don't know how to fix it. 
Thanks

error:

```
TypeError: buf is not a numerical tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

`imencode` also returns a success value. You are pickling a tuple of `(retval, buf)`. You actually want to only pickle the buf:

```
ret, frame = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
```

(Also a suggestion: save yourself some headaches down the road by actually checking the ret values).

Comment: I got it I was just encoding the tuple value. I didn't check carefully